# Javascript object syntax that I can't recognize

Tags: javascript, jsobject

I have this code snipet:

```
proxy('http://my-custom-api-endpoint.com', {
  proxyReqOptDecorator(options) {
    options.headers['x-forwarded-host'] = 'localhost:3000'
    return options
  }
})
```

It is a call to a function named proxy, the first argument is a string, but the second argument has a syntax than I can't recognize:

```
{
  functionName(args) {
    // statements
  }
}
```

Can someone explain that syntax please?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer, it's a "shorthand method name".

Comment: So, it is equivalent to:
`{ functionName: () => statement }` ?

Comment: No, it's equivalent to: `{ functionName: function () { statements } } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a shorthand method in Object Initializer to create a property whose value is a function.

> ```
> // Shorthand method names (ES2015)
> let o = {
>   property(parameters) {}
> }
> ```

```
//Before
let o = {
  property: function(parameters) {}
}
```

This syntax is also sued in classes to declare class methods.

> ```
> class Animal { 
>   speak() {
>     return this;
>   }
>   static eat() {
>     return this;
>   }
> }class Animal { 
>   speak() {
>     return this;
>   }
>   eat() {
>     return this;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Since your class example includes both static methods and uses this, you might want to clarify some of the differences or just use instance methods in the class example